# Как в на ftp-сервере переместить все файлы из одной папочки в другую?

Tags: python-3.x, ftp

```
import sys, shutil, os, ftplib
host = '00.00.00.00'
ftp_user = "***"
ftp_password = "***"
con = ftplib.FTP(host, ftp_user, ftp_password)  #законнектились на ftp
con.cwd("months/days/30/")    #перешли в папочку, из которой нужно переместить все файлы, удовлетворяющие некоторому условию, в папочку "months/days/29/"
```

Пока накидал только так. Мне нужно последовательно открывать файлы в папке "`months/days/30/`", проверять на некоторое условие и уже потом оставлять файл на месте, либо перемещать в папку "`months/days/29/`".
Таким образом, меня интересует два вопроса:

1. Как открыть текстовый файл для чтения?
2. Как переместить файл в рамках данного ftp-сервера?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461844/how-to-move-files-using-ftp-commands